# When to use a Vue mixin over a Vue directive and vice versa?

Tags: architecture, vue.js, mixins

I know this isn't necessary an explicitly obvious thing, but when deciding between a Vue mixin and a Vue directive what are some things to consider? I know if you want reuse out of a mixin it will impact all Vue components, but when you register a Vue directive does the same thing happen? Does it register in the global space? Just trying to come up with a mental model of when the mixin makes sense and when the directive makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me they don't compete with each other. A directive is used when you want to assign behavior to an HTML element. A mixin is used to extend functionality of an object. You could use a mixin *in* a directive.

Comment: Ah, gotcha! Sorry not super experienced with architecture. I guess mixins aren't as useful as I thought they were.